# Trouble with API queries using a Ruby Gem. How can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, web-applications

I'm working on a project where I pull from the Sunlight Foundation's Influence Explorer API to show what industries provide the most money to the politicians in your district.  It's a personal project where I'm learning by doing.  Fortunately, someone already created an awesome Ruby Gem called 'influence_explorer'.  My problem is that I'm a bit new to requesting JSON objects from an API.  I can't tell if I need to fork and alter this gem to fit my needs.  The reason I'm a bit confused is that in the gem methods, the JSON endpoints are already set, whereas it appears what I'm doing requires a different endpoint that is a subset of that collection of JSON objects.

So, for example.  I want to be able to pull an array of objects that have the industry and the amount they donated to a specific candidate.  I can do this just fine in the API framework.  However, when I use the gem I'm getting errors and I think it might be the gem.  I'm just not sure, because I'm a noob at this.

An example API call would be:

```
 transparencydata.com/api/1.0/aggregates/pol/f990d08287c34c389cfabe3cbf3dde99/contributors.json?cycle=2012&limit=10&apikey=b34a371adbb94d988029fec07141ed1d
```

The gem method for aggregates is:

```
module InfluenceExplorer

  class Aggregates

    def initialize(options)

       @data = InfluenceExplorer.request('aggregates.json', options)

    end

  end

end
```

The call method is:

```
module InfluenceExplorer

  def self.base_url

    'http://transparencydata.com/api/1.0/'

  end

  def self.request(endpoint, options)

    opts = options.merge('apikey' => InfluenceExplorer::Config.api_key)

    url = base_url + endpoint + "?" + opts.to_query

    # puts url

    response = JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url).to_str).collect {|i| Hashie::Mash.new(i) }

    response

  end

end

class Hash

  def to_query

    self.map{|k,v| "#{CGI.escape(k.to_s)}=#{CGI.escape(v)}"}.join("&")

  end

end

Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/influence_explorer/*.rb').each { |f| require f }
```

Do I need to create new methods to specifically call some of the sub-categories in aggregates, or am I just doing something wrong.  Thank you for any help you can provide!!!!

Gem: https://github.com/ballantyne/influence_explorer
API: http://tryit.sunlightfoundation.com/influenceexplorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the gem looks like a one-shot or a quick fix for a problem that the author had. The code only has one release and the documentation is somewhat light. There are no covering tests. It does not have complete set of endpoints, or any way to deal with requests for relational data or sub-categories. I cannot see any method in the gem that would give you something like your exampe API route nicely wrapped, although you could just do something like this:

```
results = InfluenceExplorer.request(
  "aggregates/pol/#{id}/contributors.json",
  options )
```

I cannot speak for the author, he could be very approachable and happy to spend hours chatting online about his projects, or he could be far too busy to deal with distractions from last year's open-source work. He seems to be active with open-source work in general, but more focused on node.js project work in the last year than Ruby/Rails.

I think that your options are:

- Fork this gem and add the new routes that you need.
- [Raise an issue](https://github.com/ballantyne/influence_explorer/issues) about the missing route on the gem. The author may be amenable to you submitting a pull request that adds the feature you need.

You can do both. Fork the gem, create a feature branch that adds what you want, and use that locally to solve your problem with missing functionality. If you'd like to share your work, you can push back to the fork and raise a pull request to have your changes integrated with the main gem.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually found a work around, by simply using the gem's method to request API data directly.  It adds some code, but right now I need to finish a basic version pretty quickly, so it will do.  I might fork this in the future and just add the functionality.  Thanks again!